# cost of non-clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

If I create a non-clustered index on a table, does SQL server make a copy of data in that table and stores it separately? I am just thinking about cost of creating non-clustered indexes. I guess selected by that key used in index will be faster but all inserts, updates and delete will be slow as sql server will have to maintain two copies of data. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: where and how exactly this other copy of data is stored? That what i am trying to understand

Comment: If you want to see this stuff for yourself I recommend having a play with SQL Internals Viewer (on codeplex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is not "copied" for non-clustered indices. 
A "map" of sorts (sometimes using a full copy of the indexed column[s] only) is created to make lookups faster for some queries on that field. For a basic guideline to this, think of a B-Tree
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree
where the different nodes are at well-known locations and that you can determine, based on the query, where to start looking.
Yes, you will need to spend some resources creating/maintaining the map... but how much time are you spending on searches?

The most fundamental difference between clustered and non-clustered indices in SQL Server is that a clustered index describes the physical storage order of the rows on the disk... this is why a sequential clustered index is usually preferred for good insert performance.

On the other hand, for non-clustered indices, you need to gauge the importance of search performance versus the cost of insert performance / disk space. I *usually* will use an index on any commonly searched field.
If the same field is has very frequent inserts it becomes a bit more complicated but I've never personally had to deal with insert performance convincing me not to use an index.

Comment: @Matthew. What exactly get stored on disk for this non-clustere indices. Is it this "map" of sort that is stored on the disk and SQL Server just have a copy of this map in memory as well for this table?

Comment: +Very true, btree structures must be learned first +1 for great answer, then you can get into implementation details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484.aspx

Comment: @imak, per the link ivo posted SQL Server stores index pages rather than data pages for leafs of the non-clustered index. The index pages are stored on disk (and probably loaded into memory based on use) though I can't say exactly where. I would guess in the DB file itself

Comment: A clustered index on a sequential value has better insert performance than a clustered index on a non-sequential value because it avoid page-split, not because it "describes the physical storage order of the rows on the disk".

Comment: @Stephanie Page, the clustered index absolutely does describe the physical order of rows on the disk. This is well documented and is one of the primary reasons that GUIDs for clustered indexes degrade insert performance: resorting the physical data by non-sequential values. Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131(v=sql.80).aspx "A clustered index determines the physical order of data in a table" I find it quite ironic that I have the accepted answer and so many downvotes.

Comment: And another: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639.aspx  "There can only be one clustered index per table, because the data rows themselves can only be sorted in one order"

Comment: and another: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443.aspx "The pages in the data chain and the rows in them are ordered on the value of the clustered index key. All inserts are made at the point where the key value in the inserted row fits in the ordering sequence among existing rows."

Comment: @Matthew please read my comment closely. I wasn't debating whether or not a C-I describes the physical storage. I was speaking to WHY the insert performance was improved for sequential values. the key to this is that for either a sequential value or a non-sequential the C-I STILL describes the physical order of rows. Right? But one performs better than the other because of page splits.

Comment: @Stephanie it also relates to the fact that B-Tree structures are linked lists. Inserting a random value forces links to be updated rather than adding the pointer to the last leaf. Of course there are page splits, but I'm talking about what's going on from the framework of indices, B-Tree's and data storage in general. Clustered indices on random data causes re-ordering of physical data on disk.

Comment: @Matthew, what gets "reordered". I insert a record. The page where that new record belongs gets "split". Some data stays on the existing page, some data get moved to a new page. Links are updated... why would anything else be "reordered"?

Comment: @Stephanie, the pointers in the linked list are the order. You cannot traverse the tree without them. Inserting an index record locates where it should go, copies the pointer from the previous list, inserts the record (splitting the page), sets the pointer on the previous record and adds the copied pointer to the inserted record. Now the tree map needs to be recreated to reflect the inserted record (if it caused a page split). I guess I don't see our argument here... you're taking issue with my terminology?

Answer (score 9):

SQL Server will not make a copy of all the data in the table, just the data contained in the columns of the index and any 'covering' columns, plus additional overhead data.

Yes, inserts / updates will be somewhat slower but the cost you potentially incur by not having indexes for Selects can far outweigh that. For the most part, unless you are inserting hundreds/thousands of rows per second, on a regular basis, you probably will not notice much impact on inserts / updates by having an appropriate number of indexes on a table.

We try to limit indexes on our production database but use far more indexes on our reporting database, which gets replicated from our production database. The overhead of having many indexes on a reporting databases (for inserts / updates) is not noticed.

Comment: @ivo The index pages **do** make a copy of the data (key columns, row locator, included columns) as described in this answer. leaf level index pages are really pretty similar to data pages in terms of row storage (the format has a few minor differences such as no status bits B and there isn't always a NULL BITMAP). To answer your "why" think of random vs sequential I/O.

Comment: @ivo I can assure you my description is exactly right. (I'm not sure why you are talking about "whole row" I was very explicit about stating `key columns, row locator, included columns`) It stores a row locator (File:Page:Offset for a heap or Clustered index key otherwise) but only needs to use that if the index is not fully covering. When it does need to use it this is a very expensive random I/O key lookup. You might want to read http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx

Comment: @ivo s - The thought crossed my mind that maybe we are talking at cross purposes but I don't think we are. Have you ever actually looked at the index pages in SQL Server using `DBCC IND` and `DBCC PAGE`?

Comment: @ivo Sorry but that suggestion of trying to work out what's happening by looking at the size of the mdf file is laughable. The mdf file grows in chunks according to the growth rate so at any one time will likely have unused free space. The file is divided into extents and pages `DBCC PAGE` does indeed show the contents of specific pages (formatted for human consumption) I suggest you read up on this (very well documented) area.

Comment: I take it ivo removed all of his comments. I can cobble together what he must have said, so... well done Martin!

Comment: But to be clear, the "key columns" will be included in a non-clustered index if the underlying table HAS a clustered index. Right? If the underlying table is a heap, it will have a Rowid.

Answer (score 0):

The answer also depends on whether or not you are using a [covering index](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/covering_indexes_p1.aspx) which will contain a copy of some or all of the columns in the table. The article linked to, above, does a great job of explaining the whys.